# Oracle Select query with dynamic table name

Tags: sql, oracle

I m trying to create a complicated select query which uses temp tables and syntax as below

```
with as
  table1
    (   select start_date, end_date ....somequery - returns only 1 row ),
  table2
    ( select ... somequery use table1 columns in where clause.. ),
  table3
    ( select ... use table1 columns in where clause .. )
select * from 
                select case when  ( start_date < sysdate -1000 and end_date > sysdate ) then 'table2' else 'table3' end  from table1 
         where rownum < 10
```

So logic is simple based on return value from table1 i may want to query table 2 or may want to query table3

Problem: Oracle doesnt allow table name to be dynamically generated in a sql query

I know i can write a procedure and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE but for some reason i have to do everything via a single query. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this for your main `select`:

```
select *
from table1 cross join
     table2
where start_date < sysdate - 1000 and end_date > sysdate and rownum < 10
union all
select *
from table1 cross join
     table3
where not (start_date < sysdate - 1000 and end_date > sysdate) and rownum < 10
```

The idea is to use `union all` for the two conditions and `where` to guarantee that no rows are returned subject to your conditions.  Note that this form of the `where` statement do not take into account `NULL` values for `start_date` or `end_date`.

I suspect that there might be another way to write this query, if more details about `table2` and table3` were available.

Comment: Thank you for your response.both tables has 100,000 rows as output   but for table2 the query is on a smaller set of data tables e.g. 1,000,000 but table3 queries around 10,000,000 with alot of aggregate functions. Table3 contains queries from tables that are purely like a logging tables which have variable hits corresponding to any entry made to main tables used in the query for table2. If a user wants full report thats why we prefer using table 2 else we have no choice other than to go to table3 (where query takes 3-4 minutes to come out.) I will try your solution and see if that helps.